# -[UITableViewController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7490da0'

Tags: ios, core-data

I know that the error occurs on this line as the app works just fine with this line commented out:

```
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

the error is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7490da0'

the fibroMappAppDelegate.h

```
//
//  fibroMappAppDelegate.h
//  fibromapp
//
//  Created by jamie mcallister on 09/08/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Jamie McAllister. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface fibroMappAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

and the fibroMappAppDelegate.m

```
//
//  fibroMappAppDelegate.m
//  fibromapp
//
//  Created by jamie mcallister on 09/08/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Jamie McAllister. All rights reserved.
//

#import "fibroMappAppDelegate.h"

#import "fibroMappMasterViewController.h"

@implementation fibroMappAppDelegate

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
   fibroMappMasterViewController *controller = (fibroMappMasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    [self saveContext];
}

- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } 
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"fibromapp" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"fibromapp.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible;
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


         If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

     If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
     * Simply deleting the existing store:
     [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

     * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter:
     @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES}

     Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}    

return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

@end
```

Comment: Code of fibroMappMasterViewController ?
Does it have a managedContext?

Comment: It appears from the error message that controller is a UITableviewController, not a fibroMappMasterViewController. Also, if you  are "completely new to iOS", maybe starting with a project using core data is not the best thing to do -- it is not a beginner level api.

Comment: A small side note.  Objective-C coding convention requires a capital letter for the start of class names.  You won't get a compile error but it is **strongly** suggested.

Comment: @rdelmar starting off easy isn't an option for me unfortunately, i need this app made to generate some income (i've been asked to make it for someone, i get 50% of all the profit)

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra yeh, i learned that about programming in college after i started this app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What that means is that when you do this:

```
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

The `controller` does not have a `managedObjectContext` attribute, so it's impossible to assign anything to it. You didn't post the code of `controller`, so I don't know exactly what it looks like, but the error message says that it's a `UITableViewController`. If you want to fix this problem the right way, you'll need to give `controller` a `managedObjectContext` property so that you can make this assignment work.

Comment: thanks tom and marcus, i solved this error by creating a new class that was a subclass of UITableView and adding the properties then assigning it to my first view controller

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is remove this line:

```
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

And whenever you need the managed object context in a view use:

```
[(fibroMappAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: so you mean i would use

    context = [(fibroMappAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

?

Comment: That is a less than ideal pattern.  You should be using dependency injection instead of always going to the app delegate for the MOC.  Better to actually solve the code error rather than do this.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra i did say i was knew, i havent a clue what dependenct injection is or how to do it :/ could you explain how i would do that?

@AbdullahShafique

i tried your suggestion, after importing my fibroMappAppDelegate.m into the file i added this code

`-(void)done:(id)sender{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context =  [(fibroMappAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
`
and got an error saying

"linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: Marcus was just saying that you were trying to do it right the first time, and that you should fix what you were doing instead of following this advice.

Comment: A google search will show you what dependency injection is.  As Tom said, read my answer to your question (and read Tom's) for more advice on how to properly solve this.

Comment: @JamieMcAllister Why did you uncheck my answer?

Comment: Because it is not the solution to his problem.  The solution was to subclass UITableViewController and add the property so that he can do dependency injection properly.

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that you are using a non-subclassed UITableViewController and *think* you are using a subclass that has a property called `managedObjectContext`.  Check your storyboard, xib or code and see where this is happening.

Since you are trying to use dependency injection (a very good thing btw) then I would suggest checking where you are creating the `controller` and change it so that it is using a subclass of `UITableViewController` that has the correct property.